# UIScrollView not scrolling in Xcode6

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, scroll

I'm using UIScrollViews in many projects. After the upgrade to Xcode6 the functionality
as I was using is not working anymore. it is not scrolling at all. I have this problem in many projects.
I'm NOT using auto layout.

In .h file

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
```

In .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(280,940)];

}
```

The IBOutlet is connected to the Scrollview.

Comment: try to set the content size in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: Try after set content size in ViewDidAppear.

Comment: As far as I understand the setContentSize in ViewDidAppear is only needed when using AutoLayout. Nevertheless I tried it before with no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was introduced after the upgrade to Xcode6. In Xcode5 the project was working ok. After the upgrade to Xcode6 it started behaving strangely. It appears that some connections between the .h and the Storyboard are corrupted.

Deleting this connection and reconnect did not help.
Deleting the view from the storyboard and creating/connecting it again did not help.

After spending an afternoon on this problem. I completely removed Xcode from my harddisk. And reinstalled it again (now Xcode 6.0.1).

I deleted the view from the storyboard and created it all over. No code changes.

Now it is finally working again as it was. I'm not sure if the full reinstall or the upgrade from 6.0.0 to 6.0.1 did the trick. But now I can continue. Hope this helps for someone.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of problems You get? Why do You use @property(nonatomic, retain)? 
Perhaps You could try to use @property(nonatomic, weak) instead? But still if You could be more specific regarding Your problems with UIScrollView.

Comment: Hi, I have tried the weak property also. No change in result.

Comment: Have You set scroller.minimumZoomScale and scroller.maximumZoomScale somewhere and also it's delegate? And just see if it zoom in/out?